# How do i add properly create a component to my Jhipster + Angular project with a workin routerlink?

Tags: javascript, angular, jhipster

SO i generated a new application on jhipster and i have wanted to create a front side FAQ page for my web portal, i created it as an entity and it generated all the CRUD components (detail, delete, edit). This of course in the jhipster template looks like an admin/user view table with buttons to view, edit or delete. I want to make the FAQ public to visitors of the website without needing to have an account...
So i generated a component 'faq-page' like the documentation says: https://www.jhipster.tech/using-angular/ only problem is the routerlink does not redirect me to '/faq' instead it redirects me to the 404 page.  I created the 'faq-page' component based on the existing 'home' like below snippets:

- faq-page.component.html (just has some texts for now)
- faq-page.component.ts

  ```js
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

  @Component({
    selector: 'jhi-faq-page',
    templateUrl: './faq-page.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./faq-page.component.scss']
  })
  export class FaqPageComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

  }
  ```
- faq-page.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { TestAppSharedModule } from 'app/shared/shared.module';
import { FAQ_PAGE_ROUTE } from './faq-page.route';
import { FaqPageComponent } from './faq-page.component'

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild([FAQ_PAGE_ROUTE]), TestAppSharedModule ],
  declarations: [FaqPageComponent]
})
export class FaqModule { }
```

- faq-page.route.ts

```js
import { Route } from '@angular/router';

import { FaqPageComponent } from './faq-page.component';

export const FAQ_PAGE_ROUTE: Route = {
  path: 'faq',
  component: FaqPageComponent,
  data: {
    authorities: [],
    pageTitle: 'faq-page.title'
  }
};
```

Comment: Did you use the jhipster entity sub-generator `jhipster entity faq-page --skip-server` or did you use the Angular CLI?

Comment: I used the jhipster entity sub-generator to create an FAQ entity THEN used the angular CLI to generate faq-page @JochenGebsattel

Comment: The idea is to have an 'faq entity' for admin and a page for public 'faq' @JochenGebsattel

Answer (score 0):

Check your app-routing.module.ts and make sure the `...LAYOUT_ROUTES,` line comes last!
`ng generate` will add your new component at the end, which will let the catch-all 404 page (contained in LAYOUT_ROUTES) match before your new page.
This needs to be printed somewhere in large friendly letters.

Comment: with jhipster 8 and react it should be in **routes.tsx**